# Meaning of "Loving the turkey"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Who could help me to understand the comment "Loving the turkey, it adds a little something extra to the video" to the video on Youtube? Google tells me nothing meaningful about "loving the turkey". The video itself is about some experiments in electronics.
If "the turkey" is about the speaker, why "it"?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpCQsB1VK24

Comment: Is there a turkey anywhere in the video?

Comment: @Dmitry  - "Loving the turkey" is not an idiom.  I have no idea what it refers to. Are you expecting us to watch a whole 41 minutes video, just to see if a turkey is mentioned in it?

Comment: Like @chasly-supportsMonica has said, I'm not going to watch 41 minutes of a video. Sorry mate. There is no "loving the turkey" idiom.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there has been no research and we are expected to watch a long video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer despite the fact that the question shows a lamentable lack of research on the part of the OP.

If you read just a little further down, there is a comment, "31:06... nice chicken ;)"

If you then look at the video at 31:06, there is a pottery chicken on screen.  Either this is the 'turkey' that someone was talking about, or there is another pottery figure somewhere in the video that is of a turkey.

[image: .]

Comment: haha, nice catch, but it hardly resembles a turkey

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!